# Custom cell not key value coding compliant for Runtime Attributes

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, kvc

I have a custom cell with an attribute called accessoryView.

From code I can do this:

```
NSObject* t2 = [cell valueForKey:@"accessoryView"];
NSObject* t3 = [t2 valueForKey:@"layer"];
NSObject* t4 = [t3 valueForKey:@"cornerRadius"];
```

All values are returned correctly.

When I add this in interface builder:

[image: KVC]

then I get a runtime error:
[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key accessoryView.

I don't understand why that is the case. Is it not using the same mechanism to reference the property?

Comment: The wrong one :) I changed the path to exclude accessoryView since that is the object I am adding it to and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just `layer.cornerRadius`, you dont include the name into keypath